# 0dp layout_width not working as expected for constraint layout child in recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

Minified working layout code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_item_layout_root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_item_layout_textview_fact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The above code renders the recycler view as expected.
But as per [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout),

> You cannot use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout. Instead use "match constraints" (0dp).

So, I replaced this line,

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

with this

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

But, it is not working. The `recyclerview` is not visible.

Complete repo is open-source,
https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/cat-fact

Recyclerview adapter code if required,

```
class HomeFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter :
    PagingDataAdapter<CatFact, HomeFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter.MainActivityRecyclerViewHolder>(
        CatFactDiffCallback
    ) {
    
    class MainActivityRecyclerViewHolder(private var binding: RecyclerviewItemLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(catFact: CatFact?) {
            catFact?.let {
                binding.recyclerviewItemLayoutTextviewFact.text = String.format(
                    binding.root.context.resources.getString(R.string.recyclerview_item_layout_fact),
                    catFact.id,
                    catFact.fact
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    object CatFactDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CatFact>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CatFact, newItem: CatFact): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
        
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CatFact, newItem: CatFact): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): MainActivityRecyclerViewHolder {
        return MainActivityRecyclerViewHolder(
            RecyclerviewItemLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                )
            )
        )
    }
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainActivityRecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you inflating this? Can you show the code?

Comment: @Cheticamp attached the recycler view adapter code and repo link.

Comment: on 'onCreateViewHolder()` try ` return MainActivityRecyclerViewHolder(
            RecyclerviewItemLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                ), parent, false
            )` . See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)).

Comment: @Cheticamp, Wow! It worked. Can you please add the logic behind this? Would be happy to accept the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you stated the docs say:

> You cannot use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout. Instead use "match constraints" (0dp).

The docs used to also say that the result would be unpredictable. I guess "unpredictable" means "it works" (sometimes.)

Using `0dp` is correct. The problem you are having is that the view you're inflating needs a reference to its parent view to know how big it can be, so you need to give a parent reference (2nd argument in *inflate* below)  but not attach the inflated view to the parent view (3rd argument) since the *RecyclerView* will take care of that.

```
return MainActivityRecyclerViewHolder( RecyclerviewItemLayoutBinding
    .inflate( LayoutInflater.from( parent.context ), parent, false )
```